# Effect of the distribution of inputs GPR

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

I would like to know the effect of the sampling of the inputs parameters while wanting to build a metamodel using a Gaussian Process Regression. Say you want to build an metamodel by using $N$ observations of the function $F$. You have the choice to take where your $N$ observations are between:

- on a regular grid;
- using LHS;
- random sampling;
- etc.

What is the "best" strategy? Does it have an influence on the quality of the metamodel?